# Alternative of addFileToRecord in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am having a HTML Webresource on entity form which allows me to attach a file.
i am using below command to attach the file by using the object type code, and guid of the entity record

**parent.Mscrm.RibbonActions.addFileToRecord(entityETC, entityID);**

this works fine with classic interface but unfortunately it is not supported/working in Unified Interface.
is there any alternative to achieve the same in UCI.

Answer (score 0):

In UCI this method is no more supported. The web resource which has the method addFileToRecord has been deprecated. Please check this post from the community for your reference.

> https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/397475/javascript-and-ribbon-issues-post-migration-to-unified-interface